# Why is the button in my ExtJS grid appearing as "[object Object]"?

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

In an **ExtJS grid** I have a column in which when the content of a cell is a certain value, a **button** should be displayed.

I define the column which will contain the button like this, which calls a **rendering function**:

```
{
    header: 'Payment Type',
    width: 120,
    sortable: true,
    renderer: renderPaymentType,
    dataIndex: 'paymentType'
}]
```

in the rendering function, I return either text or the **button** itself:

```
function renderPaymentType(val) {
    if(val!='creditInform') {
        return val;
    } else {
        return new Ext.Button({
            text: val,
            width: 50,
            handler: function() {
                alert('pressed');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This basically works, except that the button is displayed as the text **[object Object]**:

[image]

**What do I have to do so that the button is displayed as a button instead of as text?**

## Addendum

adding `.getEl()`:

```
function renderPaymentType(val) {
    if(val!='creditInform') {
        return val;
    } else {
        return new Ext.Button({
            text: val,
            width: 50,
            handler: function() {
                alert('pressed');
            }
        }).getEl();
    }
}
```

produces a **blank**:

[image]

adding `.getEl().parentNode.innerHTML`:

```
function renderPaymentType(val) {
    if(val!='creditInform') {
        return val;
    } else {
        return new Ext.Button({
            text: val,
            width: 50,
            handler: function() {
                alert('pressed');
            }
        }).getEl().parentNode.innerHTML;
    }
}
```

causes some kind of rendering problem with the rest of the code altough in Firebug I strangely don't get any errors:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
return new Ext.Button({
  text: val,
  width: 50,
  handler: function() {
    alert('pressed');
  }
}).getEl();
```

Your returning a JavaScript object to your renderer rather then a dom node. If doesn't work then your renderer expects a HTML string so you can try

`Ext.Button({ ... }).getEl().parentNode.innerHTML`

Either should solve your problem.

Comment: I tried both of those but they didn't work. I posted screenshots above. How else can can turn it into the expected dom node?

Comment: ExtJS expects a simple HTML string to be returned from a column renderer, so neither returning an Ext component nor returning an Ext.Element or HTML node will work.

Comment: The link provided by Gajahlemu points into the correct direction... There they use some sort of deferral approach to return a place-holder `<div>` into which the button will be rendered after some small delay.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
renderer: function (v, m, r) {
  var id = Ext.id();
  Ext.defer(function () {
    Ext.widget('button', {
      renderTo: id,
      text: 'Edit: ' + r.get('name'),
      width: 75,
      handler: function () { Ext.Msg.alert('Info', r.get('name')) }
    });
  }, 50);
  console.log(Ext.String.format('<div id="{0}"></div>', id));
  return Ext.String.format('<div id="{0}"></div>', id);
}
```

Ref: http://ext4all.com/post/how-add-dynamic-button-in-grid-panel-column-using-renderer

Comment: I was returning a 'label' object on the renderer function and I got the same message [object Object] but Patrik Khadloya solution worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you see syntax of that nature, chances are you're looking at the output of the `toString` method on an object.

Which means you're displaying the object, and not a result.

```
console.log({
 toString:function(){
   return 'toString method.'
 };
});
console.log(new Object())
Object.prototype.toString = function(){
 return 'All object to string methods are now overriden.';
}
console.log(new Object());
```

Answer (score 0):

the [API documentation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/) says this

> renderer : Mixed For an alternative to
>   specifying a renderer see xtype
>   Optional. A renderer is an
>   'interceptor' method which can be used
>   transform data (value, appearance,
>   etc.) before it is rendered). This may
>   be specified in either of three ways:
>
> - A renderer function used to return
>     HTML markup for a cell given the
>     cell's data value.
> - A string which
>     references a property name of the
>     Ext.util.Format class which provides a
>     renderer function.
> - An object
>     specifying both the renderer function,
>     and its execution scope (this
>     reference) e.g.:
>
>   {
>             fn: this.gridRenderer,
>              scope: this
>        }

You're using the renderer function option, which means your function needs to return a html markup string, rather than a new Button object. To show a button, you might need to  use the column's `editor` property