# ExtJs grid appearing as [object Object]

Tags: extjs

Help me with my code. It returns [object Object]. how can I return it as button

```
{
    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
    width: 100,
    header: 'Apply Action',
    dataIndex: 'Test',
    sortable: false,
    renderer: function(value, metadata, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
        var hasAutoAction = record.data.autoActions;
        if(hasAutoAction.length == 0){
        return '';
    }

    return '<input type="button" onClick="buttonclick(event)"  id="btn" value="Apply"/>'
    var buttonclick = function (event) {
        alert('Clicked')
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give your complete code in which function are you trying to return `button`. Actually `button` is an object. you can return object in this way. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Comment: Please give bit more information about your function.

Comment: Hi, same problem like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015453/why-is-the-button-in-my-extjs-grid-appearing-as-object-object

Comment: also tried to return onclick button on the return but the function is undefined.

Comment: return '<input type="button" onClick="buttonclick(event)"  id="btn" value="Apply"/>'
var buttonclick = function (event) {alert('Clicked')}

Comment: Here in this case you are returning an object called `button`. This is not valid.

Comment: Updated my codes above.  
Tried to return like that and apply button can now be seen but can't seem to call the function. Can you help me do a workaround? I just need to return a button on renderer and add event on that button. thanks

Comment: Hi UDID, It was actually fine in my local.. had a hard time pasting it here. Again, the problem is I can't call a function on renderer using the return button need to call a function. If you have any workaround that I can do?  btw the codes above said the buttonClick is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at [`widgetcolumn`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.grid.column.Widget.html), which should do exactly what you want, but the ExtJS way:

```
xtype:'widgetcolumn',
widget:{
    xtype:'button',
    handler:function(btn) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Clicked','Clacked');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi can I return this?
return xtype:'widgetcolumn',
     widget:{
    xtype:'button',
    handler:function(btn) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Clicked','Clacked');
    }
}

Comment: You cannot return anything. You have to drop your idea with the renderer and completely replace your `gridcolumn` with the `widgetcolumn`!

Comment: You can take a look at this problem too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015453/why-is-the-button-in-my-extjs-grid-appearing-as-object-object we basically have same problem..

Comment: Well, you are doing it wrong, and the other guy, too (but back in 2011, there was no widgetcolumn to the rescue!). **DONT USE RENDERER.** I can only recommend to look into the docs of widgetcolumn, which is why I linked to them.

Answer (score 1):

You can not return `object` in this way and therefore you getting this error. Anyway as per my understanding you wanted button in grid and and then display something on click of button. For that you don't need to write in renderer. In your previous code also you were trying to `return button` where `button` was object which is invalid.

You can change you code design and place button either in `tbar` or `bbar`.

Sample code :

```
bbar: [
  { xtype: 'button', 
    text: 'Button 1',
     handler: function() {
    alert('You clicked the button!');
   }
  }
],
```

I created a [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1gnp) for you. Try this and understand. It will work.

Comment: I still need to put it on the renderer since it dynamically displayed. And have to call a function using the return button.

Comment: It's same with this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015453/why-is-the-button-in-my-extjs-grid-appearing-as-object-object 
He provided screen shot.

Comment: @Potatooo You want button to be displayed dynamically ?

Comment: Yes. The code above is already correct. I'm displaying it dynamically but I can't call a function using the return.